Failed to process uploaded image from React with Node.js and Sharp
I am currently building a feature to upload a profile picture of the user, frontend is done and working however the backend keeps rejecting the image uploaded, even if it is a jpeg, jpg, png file type.
const storage = multer.memoryStorage(); 
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png/;
        const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
        const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());

        if (mimetype && extname) {
            return cb(null, true);
        }
        cb(new Error('Invalid file type. Only JPEG and PNG files are allowed.'));
    }
});

// Profile image upload endpoint
router.post('/upload-profile-image', upload.single('profile_img'), async (req, res) => {
    const { customer_id } = req.query;

   
    console.log('Upload request received for customer ID:', customer_id);

    if (!req.file) {
        console.log('No file uploaded.');
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'No file uploaded.' });
    }

    // Log file details
    console.log('File received:', req.file.originalname, 'Size:', req.file.size);
    console.log('MIME type:', req.file.mimetype);

    try {
        
        if (!req.file.buffer || req.file.buffer.length === 0) {
            return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Uploaded file is empty.' });
        }

       
        console.log('Buffer length:', req.file.buffer.length);

       
        console.log('Processing image...');
        let processedImage;

        
        if (req.file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
            processedImage = await sharp(req.file.buffer)
                .resize(150, 150) 
                .png({ quality: 80 }) 
                .toBuffer();
        } else if (req.file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || req.file.mimetype === 'image/jpg') {
            processedImage = await sharp(req.file.buffer)
                .resize(150, 150) 
                .jpeg({ quality: 80 }) 
                .toBuffer();
        } else {
            return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Unsupported image format.' });
        }

        // Log successful image processing
        console.log('Image processing complete. Compressed image size:', processedImage.length);

      
        if (!Buffer.isBuffer(processedImage)) {
            throw new Error('Processed image is not a valid buffer.');
        }

        const sql = 'UPDATE users SET profile_img = ? WHERE customer_id = ?';

     
        console.log('Executing SQL query:', sql);

        db.query(sql, [processedImage, customer_id], (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Database update failed:', err);
                return res.status(500).send({ error: 'Database update failed.' });
            }

           
            console.log('Profile image updated successfully for customer ID:', customer_id);
            res.status(200).send({ message: 'Profile image updated successfully.' });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to process image:', error.message);
        
        if (error.message.includes('Input buffer contains unsupported image format')) {
            return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Input buffer contains unsupported image format.' });
        }

        res.status(500).send({ error: 'Failed to process image.' });
    }
});

This is what I normally get in my backend logs:

I need help fixing the error:

Upload request received for customer ID: 2
File received: profile-image.jpg Size: 63
MIME type: image/jpeg
Buffer length: 63
Processing image...
Failed to process image: Input buffer contains unsupported image format
Error: Input buffer contains unsupported image format
    at Sharp.toBuffer (C:\Users\user\Documents\Portfolio\backend\node_modules\sharp\lib\output.js:163:17)
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\Portfolio\ustpEccomSystem\backend\routes\customerData.js:59:18
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\Documents\Portfolio\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\user\Documents\Portfolio\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at done (C:\Users\user\Documents\Portfolio\backend\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:45:7)
    at indicateDone (C:\Users\user\Documents\Portfolio\\backend\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:49:68)
    at Multipart.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Portfolio\backend\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:166:7) 
    at Multipart.emit (node:events:514:28)    
    at emitCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:132:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)


Failed to process image: Input buffer contains unsupported image format


did you make sure that the image is not corrupted, i.e. try saving it and reading it on the server. it seems that the error is coming when sharp tries to resize it and convert to buffer (at Sharp.toBuffer)

@traynor sorry for late update, however i did resolve the problem it self. it was because of my crop image feature not returning as longblob thus it return as error

yeah, I suspected it was something on the frontend...

I forgot to update my crop image feature where i should also update it as longblob but It still remain as blob type. thus the issue of the sharp not saving and reading is because of the crop image feature of mine... anyways thank you
export const getCroppedImg = (imageSrc, croppedAreaPixels) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = imageSrc;

    image.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // Set canvas size
      canvas.width = croppedAreaPixels.width;
      canvas.height = croppedAreaPixels.height;

      ctx.drawImage(
        image,
        croppedAreaPixels.x,
        croppedAreaPixels.y,
        croppedAreaPixels.width,
        croppedAreaPixels.height,
        0,
        0,
        croppedAreaPixels.width,
        croppedAreaPixels.height,
      );

      // Convert to Blob and resolve
      canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
        if (!blob) {
          reject(new Error('Canvas is empty'));
          return;
        }

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
          // Convert ArrayBuffer to a new Blob
          const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
          const longBlob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
          resolve(longBlob); // Resolve with the LONG BLOB
        };

        // Read the blob as an ArrayBuffer
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
      }, 'image/jpeg');
    };

    image.onerror = () => {
      reject(new Error('Failed to load image'));
    };
  });
};

